# Getting ../include/mem.h not found while building using Android Studio

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk

I am building a native app using Android Studio. I installed ndk-bundle and I cannot find mem.h in there. Couldn't find any solutions online. Can some one help me here?

Here is the error I get:

> C:\Users\pvenkatayogi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\stlport\stlport\mem.h
>   Error:(40, 14) '../include/mem.h' file not found
>
> C:\Users\pvenkatayogi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\stlport\stlport\stl\config_android.h
>   Information:(59, 39) expanded from macro '_STLP_NATIVE_C_HEADER'

Comment: file `config_android.h` does not appear in NDK for stlport, as far as I can tell. Therefore, it is quite possible that clean reinstall of NDK will help. Delete `C:\Users\pvenkatayogi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle`, download the latest NDK ZIP from the [official site](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html), and unzip it into `C:\Users\pvenkatayogi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle`.